# SAS: add suffix to macro variable

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I am fitting an example model in SAS:

```
proc mixed data = pat_ehp30 method = reml;
    class trt_group AssNo stage_endo_cat opinofsurg age_cat larc_selection larc_decision recruitcent;
    model infertile = trt_group AssNo AssNo * trt_group infertile0 stage_endo_cat opinofsurg age_cat larc_selection larc_decision / s cl;
    repeated AssNo / type = cs sub = Pat_TNO r rcorr;
    random recruitcent;
    lsmeans trt_group * AssNo / slice = AssNo diff cl e;
run;
```

I am fitting the same model 11 times, with the only difference being the output is different and I'm adjusting for baseline (in this case the variable `infertile0`). I have written a macro:

```
%macro rm (domain = ,);
    proc mixed data = pat_ehp30 method = reml;
        class trt_group AssNo stage_endo_cat opinofsurg age_cat larc_selection larc_decision recruitcent;
        model &domain = trt_group AssNo AssNo * trt_group &domain0 stage_endo_cat opinofsurg age_cat larc_selection larc_decision / s cl;
        repeated AssNo / type = cs sub = Pat_TNO r rcorr;
        random recruitcent;
        lsmeans trt_group * AssNo / slice = AssNo diff cl e;
    run;
%mend rm;
```

However the variable `&domain0` will not work. I want it to append a `0` to the end of whatever name I put into `domain`, eg `pain` becomes `pain0`.

Answer (score 0):

Variable &domain0 will not work, because you don't have it defined. If you want appended names, you have to use &domain.0, like this:

```
%macro rm (domain = ,);
    proc mixed data = pat_ehp30 method = reml;
        class trt_group AssNo stage_endo_cat opinofsurg age_cat larc_selection larc_decision recruitcent;
        model &domain = trt_group AssNo AssNo * trt_group &domain.0 stage_endo_cat opinofsurg age_cat larc_selection larc_decision / s cl;
        repeated AssNo / type = cs sub = Pat_TNO r rcorr;
        random recruitcent;
        lsmeans trt_group * AssNo / slice = AssNo diff cl e;
    run;
%mend rm;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a period to tell the macro processor where the name of the macro variable ends.   Otherwise the macro processor will assume the name stops when it sees a character that could not be part of the name.

```
  &domain.0
```

Note this means that if you wanted the next character to be an actual period you will need to type two periods.  The first to end the macro variable name and the second to become part of the code being generated.

```
 filename out "&path/&basename..txt" ;
```

Comment: Don't you mean:  filename out "&path./&basename..txt" ; ?